# Closure value changes without being reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-bootstrap-table

**NOTE THAT THIS IS SOLVED**

I don't expect someone to solve the problem because there is lots of code missing but maybe I'm missing something here.

I'm creating a closure in mergeProps to be used as a delete action. It gets `selectedItems` from state or data from server if form is not touched yet. User can remove or add items from the list but when I add 2 and then remove the top item something strange happens.

According to the logs the closure is not re created but the length of selectedItems is 1 (it's missing one without the closure being re created).

This happens in both Chrome and firefox, the code is:

```
const mergeProps = (
  stateProps,
  dispatchProps,
  ownProps,
) => {
  //make a copy of selected items to be used for the closure of
  //  onDelete in case but is caused by other code mutating it
  const copy = JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(stateProps.selectedItems || []),
  );
  console.log(
    new Date().getTime(),
    'creating closure, length is:',
    copy.length,
  );
  return {
    ...stateProps,
    ...ownProps,
    onDelete: ({ id: entityId, entityType }) =>
      console.log(
        'in the closure, length is now:',
        copy.length,
      ) ||
      onDeleteDataFilter(
        entityId,
        entityType,
        ownProps.onChange,
        copy,
      ),
  };
};
```

When I add 2 items and remove the top item the output of the console is:

```
1553159774414 creating closure, length is: 2 
in the closure, length is now: 1
1553159785005 creating closure, length is: 0
```

To me it seems impossible that `copy` can be changed without close being called again but that is what I'm getting.

The selectedItems were rendered by react bootstrap table and this seems to have it's own state so each row gets it's own `onDelete` function.

Closure variables changing can only happen when you mutate the variable and in this case I just logged the wrong thing thinking the array was changed but instead each row in the bootstrap table got it's own closure function (see answer).

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Looking at the code it seems impossible that the array length of `copy` changes but that was what seemed to happen. The problem was actually that the list of `selected items` each have their own closure.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Should I leave this up? Been banging my head to solve this for quite some time however the solution is obvious: of course the closure value can't change unless re created but each row of selected items has their own closure.

Comment: If you can update the question with an MCVE demonstrating the problem, then solve it in your answer, that might help someone else in the future. For me (and it's just me), the key thing is the question should have all the necessary information to answer it, separate from your answer. But no reason you can't edit to do that if you think it'll help others. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was caused by the selected items being passed to BootstrapTable and somehow each row in that table gets **their own closure function**. So I add one item named `A` that has a delete action with with `selectedItems` of `[A]`. I add `B` it has a closure function with `selectedItems` of `[A,B]`. Removing B will work but removing A will fail because it doesn't have the correct closure function.

When adding a counter on the closure I could see that the number of the counter was not correct for items that were not the last item:

```
let counter = 1;
const mergeProps = (
  stateProps,
  dispatchProps,
  ownProps,
) => {
  const copy = JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(stateProps.selectedItems|| []),
  );
  const copyCounter = counter;
  counter++;
  console.log('creating closure for counter:', copyCounter);
  return {
    ...stateProps,
    ...ownProps,
    onDelete: ({ id: entityId, entityType }) =>
      console.log(
        'in the closure, counter is:',
        copyCounter,
      ) ||
      onDeleteDataFilter(
        entityId,
        entityType,
        ownProps.onChange,
        copy,
      ),
  };
};
```

### Solution

To force react bootstrap table and use the same onDelete functions for every row I added a unique key `key={new Date().getTime()}` this will run the constructor and did mount so the onDelete in the props will be the same for every row.